# How to remove element one by one with same class after scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a column of 15 squares with a class of "box".

I expect to remove them from body only one by one after scroll down.

I tried this but nothing happens:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($('.box:first').offset().top + $('.box:first').height() < $(window).scrollTop()) {

       $(this).remove(); 
       };
})
```

Any suggestions ?

http://jsfiddle.net/e1m1bmd4/1/

Comment: `$(this) ` in `$(this).remove();` refers to the window object, not any of your divs.

Comment: Looks like i need more documentation. Thank you for correcting me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `$(this)` with `$'.box:first').remove()`. Because `$(this)` refers to the window scroll object not the box element.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/e1m1bmd4/7/)

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` refers to the window object as you have it. Be more specific:

```
if ( $('.box:first').offset().top 
  + $('.box:first').height() <  $(window).scrollTop() ) {
    $('.box:first').remove();
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/e1m1bmd4/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first()`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($('.box').first().offset().top + $('.box').first().height() < $(window).scrollTop()) {

       $('.box').first().remove(); 
       };
})
```

And refer to current 1st box class Not window which you had in code.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1m1bmd4/16/)**

Comment: I will be more carefully next time. Thank you :)